# How to place a Layout over another and avoid the one under being clicked

Tags: android, android-layout

I've placed `LinearLayout` over another. It's like a floating menu with transparency but the problem is that the layout under it can be actually clicked even though the `LinearLayout` with transparency is over it.

I hope you understand what I mean.

Is there any way I can avoid that? (I'd rather don't disable `clickListener` from the layout under..)

Comment: I've solved it by creating a clickListener for the LinearLayout and doing nothing on that clickListener..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it by creating a `clickListener` for the `LinearLayout` and doing nothing on that `clickListener`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Frame` layout for above and under view. Then dispatch `false` for Below view for `onTouch` event.
like this

```
belowView.setOnTouchListner(new View.onTouchListner(){
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
        return false;
    }
});
```