# How to place one layout on another layout

Tags: android, android-layout, ontouchlistener

I have a question. I am working on a layout wherein I want one layout to be above the other layout.
Situation: There is one RelativeLayout which has a Touchlistener. At the bottom of this layout, there is anothet relative layout having three buttons which are clickable. Now the problem is when I click on one these buttons, the listener of the first layout gets activated and none of the buttons work.

I did make use of frame layout but its not working. Did make use of .bringToFront method. But this did not work also.

Please I need suggestions for the same.

I am uploading my code.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rlayout" 
    android:layout_width="458dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="278dp"
    android:background="@drawable/anim_layout" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

 </RelativeLayout>

     <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/more"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@drawable/image_unfocus" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rlayout_anim_bg"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:background="@drawable/anim_bg" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/sequence_image"
        android:layout_width="22dip"
        android:layout_height="17dip"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dip"
        android:background="@drawable/unfocus_image" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/edit_image"
        android:layout_width="22dip"
        android:layout_height="17dip"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/sequence_image"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_icon" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/close_image"
        android:layout_width="22dip"
        android:layout_height="17dip"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/edit_image"
        android:background="@drawable/close_img" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Check this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367743/how-to-place-a-layout-over-another-and-avoid-the-one-under-being-clicked

Comment: I did check the link...and tried it as well but its not working.

Comment: In my case both the layouts have listeners

Answer (score 0):

use Layout Inflator ... make an xml . with the use of inflator , you can inflate another layout over the previous one.
enjoy